# conditional statement if is_page for multiple pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to target multiple pages by IDs using if is_page conditional statement in wordpress. This is what I have:

```
if ( is_page('222','223') ) {
        echo 'content for pages 222 and 223';
    }
```

however this is only working for first page

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Wordpress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/), the is_page() function accepts integers, strings and arrays.  Try passing in an **array** of IDs, such as the following:

```
if(is_page([222,223])) { 
    echo 'content for pages 222 and 223';
    return true; 
} else { 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: if (is_page( array('portal/work','portal/blogs', '

How do I shortcut this one? can i do something like : array('portal/.*)); I don't know how to reduce the amount of characters there.